# How to match against multiple dynamic url parts with webpackInclude?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have dynamic import with multiple variables:

```
import(`./locale/${country}/${language}.json`)
```

When I add a "magic" *webpackInclude* comment:

```
/* webpackInclude: /\.json$/ */
```

it is only matched against the second variable. How do I write a regexp that can match the whole path string?

There's no example or explanation in the official documentation: https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/

Comment: it is aready a regex, just improve it!

Comment: Clear. But it is matched against "language" only. I need something like "de/\(.?)/\.json$" to match against both variables "country" and "language", which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The [`webpackInclude` regex](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/1736808f50ec75ffef1f4f2f1e058141e61ea7ef/lib/dependencies/ImportParserPlugin.js#L122-L136) is [applied to the entire path](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/1736808f50ec75ffef1f4f2f1e058141e61ea7ef/lib/ContextModuleFactory.js#L311-L332), not individual variables.

If you wanted to match specific countries, then you could use a regex like:

```js
/* webpackInclude: /[/](USA|CAN)[/]/ */
```

Or if you wanted to match specific languages files within those specific countries, then you could use something like:

```js
/* webpackInclude: /[/](USA|CAN)[/](en|fr)\.json/ */
```

The above pattern would match the paths:

```
./locale/CAN/en.json
./locale/CAN/fr.json
./locale/USA/en.json
./locale/USA/fr.json
```

but would not match:

```
./locale/GBR/en.json
./locale/USA/es.json
```